# Hybris SAP CX Addon for Commerce Service - there is no resource for path

Tags: web-services, hybris-data-hub

In my clone source project, there are a **addon** and a **webservice** extension. Inside addon, I define new API in controller with path: `{baseSiteId}/product/variants?productId={productid}`

After building project: `ant all`. The code of new API in **addon** is generated in the **webservice** extension.

After stating server: `hybrisserver.bat debug`. I opened the /v2/swagger-ui.html but I can't find the new API, it only has some existed APIs in **webservice** ext.

I call to the new API by postman, the error display as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<errors>
    <error>
        <message>There is no resource for path /webservice/v2/MySite/product/variants?productId=43546426</message>
        <type>UnknownResourceError</type>
    </error>
</errors>
```

I appreciated any helps for this.
Thank you

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Just link again the addon the the extension. Run the following commant: `ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="addon-name" -DaddonStorefront.ycommercewebservices="webservices-extension"`
Then build and start server.

Comment: This is a big question here: is this still valid.